# Unexpected end of JSON input error after pending promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am in the process of creating a data handler and as part of that I need to download a file to then parse and work with as part of the handler.

I have wrapped the request for the file in a promise and asynchronously called the method from other methods

I have included the handler from a separate test file as follows

```
let DataHandler = require('./handler');

const handler = new DataHandler();

console.log(handler.getSupervisors());
```

The `getSupervisors` method is as follows

```
async getSupervisors() {
    const parsed = await this.loadFile();
    let supervisorList = [];

    parsed.controllers.map(controller => {
        if (controller.rating === 11 || controller.rating === 12){
            supervisorList.push(controller);
        }
    });

    return supervisorList;
}
```

This calls the `loadFile` method which simply calls the `update` method and before returning the json file required. The next 2 methods are `update` and `downloadFile` which I think are my 2 issues, they are as follows

```
async update() {    
    let body = await this.downloadFile();
    const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(body);

    parsedJSON.updated_date = new Date();
    const json = JSON.stringify(parsedJSON);
    fs.writeFile('vatsimData.json', json, function(err, result) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
    });
}

downloadFile() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const urlList = [
            'http://us.data.vatsim.net/vatsim-data.json',
            'http://eu.data.vatsim.net/vatsim-data.json',
            'http://apac.data.vatsim.net/vatsim-data.json'
        ];
        const url = urlList[Math.floor(Math.random()*urlList.length)];
        request(url, (error, response, body) => {
            if (error) reject(error);

            if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
                reject('Invalid status code <' + response.statusCode + '>');
            }

            resolve(body);
        });
    });
}
```

The output of the `getSupervisors` method should be an array of all the 'supervisors' within the json file, instead it returns `Promise { <pending> }` and this error

```
(node:3160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at DataHandler.loadFile (D:\Projects\VATSIM-Data-Handler\handler.js:57:15)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:3160) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:3160) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I have tried putting the whole of the `update` method within a `.then` callback after calling `downloadFile` but it did not work

My loadFile method is as follows

```
async loadFile(){
    await this.update();
    return(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('vatsimData.json', {encoding:'utf-8'})));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting a promise is because, you are not `await`ing the `async` function when you `console.log(handler.getSupervisors());`

you should do

```
handler.getSupervisors.then(val => console.log(val));
```

The error may be because the `body` response from the server may be malformed. try `console.log` body before calling `JSON.parse()` and use `try catch` to wrap and prevent unhandled errors

**Update**
From comments, you are trying to parse a file read with incorrect encoding

```
console.log(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('vatsimData.json',{encoding:'utf-8'})));
```

Add the encoding value in options.

**Update**

```
async update() {    
    let body = await this.downloadFile();
    const parsedJSON = JSON.parse(body);

    parsedJSON.updated_date = new Date();
    const json = JSON.stringify(parsedJSON);
    fs.writeFileSync('vatsimData.json', json, function(err, result) {
        if(err) console.log(err);
    }); // convert it to sync or resolve with a new promise when you complete the write to wait for the loadFile to have the file ready
}
```

Comment: I've added the code you have mentioned but now it doesn't log anything to the console, I tried doing `console.log(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('vatsimData.json')));` before the return in the `loadFile` method but nothing gets logged

Comment: The problem is that readFileSync reads a buffer and not text, you must pass argument {encoding: 'utf-8'} as second argument

Comment: but the problem you have is something else, `console.log(JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('vatsimData.json')));` this would just throw an error for unable to parse the file

Comment: wait, this should be the parse error you had! I think you have written that code in loadFile which tries to parse wrong encoded file read!

Comment: I am still getting the `Unexpected end of JSON input` error

Comment: Post the contents of your loadFile method, because you have to await the update call before returning the contents of the JSON file

Comment: you are not awaiting for the write operation to complete!

Comment: To think that simply adding `Sync` could fix about 3 hours of head scratching, thank you so much @DhananjaiPai

Comment: `Sync` and `encoding`! :D